# I solved the question. But I am asking a little bit. $\det\big(D(f\circ g)(a)\big)=?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, determinant

> $\color{red}{\text{b)}}$ If $n=m$ and $f:B_r\big(g(a)\big)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, prove that $$\det\big(D(f\circ g)(a)\big)=\det\big(Df(g(a))\big)\det\big(Dg(a)\big)$$ Solution: $$D(f\circ g)(a)=Df(g(a))Dg(a)\quad\text{by the chain rule.}$$

After here, how can I show its determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:B_r(g(a))\subset \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and $g:\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ both of class $\mathcal C^1$. With $\Omega$ we denote an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. We select the point

$$a=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$

in $\Omega$, with $g(a)=(y_1\dots,y_n)$. By the chain rule

$$ (D(f\circ g)(a))_{ij}:=\frac{\partial f_i }{\partial y_k}\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_j}= \sum_{k=1}^n(D(f)(g(a))_{ik}D(g)(a)_{kj},$$

i.e.

$$D(f\circ g)(a)=D(f)(g(a))D(g)(a),~~(*)$$

as you correctly remarked. Eq. $(*)$ is an equality of $n\times n$ matrices. As

$$\operatorname{det}(AB)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B),~~ (**)$$

for all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, then you arrive at the statement. You can prove (**) using the Cauhy-Binet formula shown in [Cauchy-Binet formula for determinants.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula)